# take derivative of a function where the variable is a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, derivatives

Suppose $f(x) = || x - b||^2$ where $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, what is the expression of $f'(x)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. It would be the gradient $\nabla f$, not derivative $f^\prime$.
2. For the second norm the gradient looks as follows
   $$\nabla f = 2(x - b)\in \mathbb{R}^n$$